# Getting weird output when concatenating a string and copying it into an array

Tags: c, arrays, string-concatenation

I'm working on a function that takes characters from a file in amounts specified by the user and concatenates them into a string that will be stored into an array. The user would be prompt for a directory and amount of characters to be concatenated. However, when I tried doing this and printed out the results I got weird symbols and numbers like so;

> @ؙ>\212\377`\366\277_\377g

Could anyone shed some light to why this might be happening. Thank you. Info: this is in main() right now, `fileNames` is the list of file names within the directory.

```
/*struct def*/
typedef struct arr{
char *wordd;
int indx;
}ARR;

/* Dynamic  array of structs*/
ARR arr[COUNTER];
char wordConct[81];

for (i = 0 ; i < count; i++) {
    sprintf( fullName, "%s/%s", directoryName, fileNames[i]); //DIRECTORY/FILENAME FORMAT

    /*Read in from file*/
    inFile = fopen( fullName, "r");
    assert( inFile);

    /* This loop concatenates input then stores in array */
    while( fscanf( inFile, "%c", word) != EOF) {
        if (isalnum(*word) != 0) { // Only goes through if alphanumeric
            //nChar is user specified number of characters to be concatenated
            if (j <= nChar) {
                strcat(wordConct, word); //concatenates
                j++; //add 1 to j to count until nChar is reached
            }
            else {
            //copy concatenated word into the array once nChar is reached
                strcpy(arr[j].wordd, wordConct); 
            }
                    j = 0; //reset back to zero for next iteration               
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in a debugger, examined the variables, etc?

Comment: Yes, within every every if, else if to see if it was even going passed those point and it seems to be working correctly.  I have not tried the debugger though.

Comment: `wordConct` needs to be a valid C-style string. Right now it's just garbage. Initialize it to zero.

Comment: Can you shed some light on what `ARR` is? I am a little confused because you are using `j`, which will at that point be the user-specified length limit, to reference into an array of `ARR` types and do a `strcpy`...something about that seems fishy to me.

Comment: And reinitialize it in each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: @wilkesybear `ARR` is my typedef struct that I declared to store the string and the index of the string within the array. j is being used as a counter so that the loop knows when it has reached the length.

Comment: Post a full (minimal) working program that people can compile and run. There's no point looking at this with so much left out.